# Permission denied ssh on ubuntu

Tags: ssh, ubuntu

I m trying to ssh my rpi from ubuntu terminal and I get permission denied(publickey,password).

The password is correct and I still get this error.

Even so, when I try connecting from putty on windows, it works fine.

Antoher weird thing, I ve set up a static ip address for the pi to connect from putty, but on Ubuntu it only works with the default ip address, not the static IP.

Thx

Comment: Are you sure you use the right user name (default `pi`) when using `ssh`?

Comment: Yes, the default username.

Comment: I even tried with ssh root@ip. Still same problem.

Comment: Try `ssh -v -v pi@host` to get some more debugging info.

Comment: Connection is established on port 22, then key_load_public no such file, then public key, host is known, then auth method password. I enter the password, access denied..

Comment: Sure you are typing the right password? Think of different keyboard layouts...

Comment: The password is 100% correct. Same keyboard layout used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone encounters this issue again near time soon, so I will post my solution.

After many tries and many blogs/tutorials/documentation I ve read, nothing seemed to work. So I just unplugged the ethernet cable, put the rpi on a screen and did the following

1. $sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
2. $ifconfig
   after the $ifconfig command you will get a list with eth0, lo, wlan0
   I noted the ip address from the wlan0 part
3. ssh user@wlan0ipaddress
4. amazing, ssh over Wi-Fi, no cables, life is good.

Thanks everyone for their support so far.
Wish you an amazing life.

Comment: But how do you explain that you could ssh from Windows?

Comment: before reinstall next time you might want to read the logfile first (should be `/var/log/auth.log`), ssh shows pretty detailled why a login fails

Comment: @Jos I wish I could. On the windows I took laptop s ip from ipconfig and then set a static ip on the raspberry by changing the last 2 digits. I tried using that ip on the ubuntu as well, did not work. I would add this to the wonders of the 21st century.